# Apple Interface Builder warning: The content rectangle doesn't lie entirely on screen with the menu and may not be completely visible for all screens

Tags: interface-builder, warnings

A warning comes up in a MainMenu.XIB dialogue box.  It says:

`Object: window(window) 
ID: 371
Type: Illegal Configuration
Issue: This windows content rectangle does not lie entirely on the screen with the menu bar and may not be completely visible for all screen resolutions and configurations.`

I saw something related to this issue on StackOverflow, but it did not help.  Here was the prior response:

> In Interface builder select the window and then from the inspector go to the window size tab and move the window away from the left edge. This will get rid of the warning.

Answer (score 78):

1. Select window by it's title bar.
2. Open sizing and positioning tab (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+ <kbd>5</kbd> in Xcode4 and Xcode5) in inspector panel.
3. Adjust it's position on the desktop so that it is somewhere in the middle of it.

Comment: I had this problem too (in Xcode 4), but in my case I had the window setup to be centered automatically in IB. So the last thing that crossed my mind was that the window was detected outside of the screen. Just clicking and dragging on the window in the inspector panel fixed it (even though the window didn't move in the preview area due to its constraints).

Comment: Why would Apple make it so that the preview placement of the window has anything to do with the final output.  Bad design.  I hope Xcode 4 fixed this. It appears that it might have.

Comment: Same here - was set to *Center Hor./Vert.* => Warning. Switched back to manual positioning, dragged around in preview area a bit, switched back to auto center => All Good. Silly Bug! (**Xcode 4.2**)

Answer (score 18):

I had the same problem with Xcode 4.5.2

What I ended up doing is also clicking on the window's title bar -> "Show the size inspector" tab.

Then I just toggled the struts & springs in the preview area. Without really changing anything other than toggling on/off.

[image: Toggling these fixed the warning.]

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me.

For me it seems that my MainWindow's width was too large. I found that at a 1024 it quit giving me the warning!